# How to control media volume?

Tags: android

I would like to control media volume with my app using regular volume buttons.
The problem is my app is using short sounds, and they might be annoying for the user. You can only adjust media volume while they are playing (for 1 sec) then it starts to adjust ringer volume.
How can I make media volume default?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In your activity's onCreate() you can do:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: @Kevin: +1, I didn't know about that method - a bit simpler than my approach. ;-)

Comment: What should I do if I want two volume control streams?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this but you should be able to intercept the regular volume buttons by overriding `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` in your Activity. Check for keycodes `KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP` and `KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN`.

Using [AudioManager.setStreamVolume(int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) with `STREAM_MUSIC` for the `streamType` parameter should work and if you return `true` from the `onKeyDown(...)` method (to indicate you've handled the event), it should prevent the system from adjusting the ringer volume. Make sure you return `false` for all other keycodes that you're not handling.

Comment: What should I do if I want two volume control streams?

Answer (score 3):

**Please don't handle the volume keys yourself** - it is almost impossible to guarantee that you won't break the behavior of the volume keys.

Call this API in your `onCreate():`

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

This tells the **AudioManager** that when your `application has focus`, the volume keys should adjust the music volume.