# Android - Service, MediaPlayer and setVolume

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I have a service with MediaPlayer in it. From Activity I need to change Player's volume. Any ideas?
P.S. I very need your help
P.P.S. Sorry for my English, please

Comment: @Rani, yes, I'm using SeekBar in Activity. In it's listener, in onStopTrackingTouch() I need to change the volume of MediaPlayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a local `Service` and you have not forced it to run into another thread, you can define a method to set the `MediaPlayer`'s volume, bind to the `Service` from the `Activity`, and call the method directly. See the "Local Service Sample" [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to see how to bind to a `Service`. Once you have bound to the `Service`, you can cast the `IBinder` you receive to an instance of your `Service` class to use its methods.

If it is not a local `Service` or if you have made it run in a separate thread, you will need to communicate with the `Service` via a `Messenger`/`Handler` or using an `Intent`. There is a "Remote Messenger Service Sample" in the same link from before.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you..

```
protected static void setVolume(int volume) {
        currentVolume = volume;
        {
            if (volume == 1) {
                volume = 2;
            }
            try {
                float vol = ((float) volume / CONSTANT.SYSTEM_MAX_VOLUME);
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(vol, vol);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784687/how-to-control-media-volume)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But when I must place this code, and how call this method?

Comment: where you want to change the volume ??

Comment: I want to change volume of Service's MediaPlayer, and I don't want to use AudioManager