# React Native: Volume Button Should Only Control Media (Android)

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I would like to know how can I force **volume buttons** to only control **media** while in my application.

I know this is an android specific question and ios does this by default.

There are two related questions giving android solutions:

[*Volume Control in android application*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539264/volume-control-in-android-application)

[*How can I manage audio volumes sanely in my Android app?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628659/how-can-i-manage-audio-volumes-sanely-in-my-android-app/674207)

They both suggest adding `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` to android but I'm a `react-native` developer and not familiar with `java`.

There is also this react-native related question:

[How to control media volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784687/how-to-control-media-volume)

Which gives me no idea on where `onCreate()` is.

**Any Specific suggestions on where to add this line in java part of react-native?**

Comment: İf you created your app via react-native-cli (not expo) you can open android project on Android Studio and add 'setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);' line to your onCreate method at MainActivity. But in Expo that is impossible.

Comment: @VolkanSahin45 Thank you sir, this helped a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I did some research and thanks to @VolkanSahin45 for his comment, I figured it out.

Adding `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` was right.

What I had to do was to `Override` the `onCreate()` function inside `MainActivity.java`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    /* Any previous code you had here */
    [...]

    /* Override the onCreate function here */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* Add this line to keep the original behavior of onCreate() */
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* This one does the trick */
        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
}
```